# The program detects its own click so it stops

Tags: python, mouse

Trying to make an autoclicker that clicks only when the left mouse button is pressed. Unfortunately the program itself detects that the button has been released so I stop clicking. Is there any option to check if program or mouse is clicking? Or to make it work? I am not interested in changing button to another one. Only left mouse button.

```
import mouse
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    while mouse.is_pressed("left"):
        mouse.click('left')
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution

```
import time, pyautogui, win32api
import win32api, win32con

while True:
    time.sleep(0.076)
    if win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)<0:
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
```